# storing vehicle tracking data in differnt table and delete many data after Specified time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

im developing vehicle tracking  I think in a very short period of time, the data will be be enormous because the gps device send many data in day, when we track many device  These data will be enormous ......
i want  create some table for these data,( table for data of current day, and table for 3days and table for 1 week data and table for 3 weeks data and one month and after 3 month we get backup) 
but for Implement this scenario  i dont know how can delete many data after 3 month and store related data to the self table 
thnx for your guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the day, the week, month,and the year and use a combined index with all those columns plus the userid.hope it helps

Comment: thnx for replay but I don't want all the data to be stored in a table  and have more than a year's worth of data in the database

Comment: I agree with. you can create a table called currentyear.and the other one will have archive.an use the previous indexes cited above in both tables

Comment: احسنت خالد, and when complate 1 year how can delete these big data because after backup i don't want these data to stay in the data base

Comment: شكرا محمد.You can use a stored procedure that periodically executes to migrate every column that doesn't belong to the current year

Comment: thnax alot ,it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have a deletion issue (or a backup issue) for large chunks of data, then the solution is to *partition* your data, in your case probably by day.

Each partition is stored in a separate location.  You can think of it as a file.  Dropping partitions is very fast.  On the other hand, deleting rows can be quite expensive, because each deleted row needs to be logged.  In some databases, that can fill up log space, preventing the deletion.

On the other hand, partitions can be invisible when you are querying.  They can also speed up queries, so queries that use only one day's worth of data only needs to read that data.  They are also compatible with indexes.

You haven't specified your database, but pretty much all databases support partitioning or something similar.

Comment: thnx for your replay, i used sql server 2017, I want to break one year's data into 4 sections or 4 tables, each table containing 3 months of information, and after each new chapter, new data is entered in new table  and the previous table is completely deleted. do u have beter Ideas?

Comment: @mohamad . . . I think the answer is pretty clear.  One table.  Multiple partitions.